# When Dialog meets videoview

Tags: android, video, dialog

I have create a `Dialog` in my project. Now I have to play video in it.
And I have bound `Mediacontroller` to `Videoview`. There I meet a problem.

The controller doesn't work. I guess `requestFocus()` failed.
Now I plan to use `popupwindow` to resolve it, but I still hope someone can
tell me how to handle it in simply way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create a custom dialog class and override the dispatchTouchEvent method.
When you recieve a touch in the dialog bounds use a handler to send the message to your activity to control the video.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
        getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

        if (dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {

                    //dispatch handler from here

            }
       }

}
```